# How can an object literal's property be assigned to the return value of one of its methods?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, methods, properties, variable-assignment

So I am making a game to practice using the mvc paradigm. I create an object literal for my model and want the functions it needs to generate values for its properties to be in the object itself. I have tried this with no success. I have tried using "this" when calling the function and not using it. Either way, I get a function not defined error from chrome. What can I do to fix this? Here's the relevant code:

```
var model = {
genPlayers: function() {
        return tempPlayerArray;
    },
 playerArray: genPlayers()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. 1. there is no function with the name `genPlayers()` only `model.genPlayers()` and 2. object properties can't be accessed during object initialization.

What you could do is:

```
var model = {
    genPlayers: function() {
        return tempPlayerArray;
    },
    playerArray: null
};

model.playerArray = model.genPlayers();
```

Or if `model.genPlayers` always only returns the `tempPlayerArray` you could do this:

```
var model = {
    genPlayers: function() {
        return tempPlayerArray;
    },
    playerArray: tempPlayerArray
};
```

Comment: "Object properties can't be accessed during object initialization." This is what I needed to know! Thanks so much!